# Bevel - how can I get this done nicely

Tags: mesh

How do I apply a bevel to this so that it becomes nicely (half) round?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). What's the original shape of the geometry? And what exactly is your goal? (simply mark it in the image)

Comment: I can make a cylinder and cut it in half, but then I don't get it connected to the rest of the mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not necessary here, but for a more CAD-like approach, with arc-of circle fillets..

**To make a semicircular arc between two parallel faces**

[image]

If the faces are cut off orthogonally, then you can select the two end-edges and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Cursor to Selection.. and then in a top view use the Spin tool from the<kbd>T</kbd> toolbar to connect them. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to get an exact semicircle.

**For a smooth fillet, not necessarily circular**

You can just use 'Bridge Edge Loops', with 'Blend Surfaces' set, and adjust the smoothness....

[image]

**To make an arc-of-circle tangential to two skew faces**

A bit more involved. Using the shipped 'TinyCAD' add-on:

[image]

1. Use its 'BIX' *Bisector of 2 Planar Edges* operator to construct the bisector of the angle between the faces
2. Drop a perpendicular from one of the points where the arc is going to meet the faces. You could do this by creating  [Custom Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations) from the face, and <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> extruding a vertex normal to the face.
3. Use TinyCAD again, 'V2X', Vertex at Intersection between the two new edges  you have made.

That will be the center for using the Spin tool..

[image]

This time, you will have to eyeball the connection,(or rotate the last edge about the cursor a tiny bit, with snap,and use *Loop Tools > Space* for an arc that is at least as good as its polygonal approximation,) but you can zoom in while the tool is in use.

In both cases, <kbd>M</kbd> > Merge > By Distance will weld your new vertices to the old ones.

Comment: Now someone is going to find the add-on which does it in one :D

Comment: I already had the adon "TinyCAD", but not yet studied well enough, but with this explanation it will now work fine.

Thank you very much all, I used Robin Betts answer to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by creating a single edge in the middle (if you don't need to create a loop like I do here with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then you can just select top and bottom edge and subdivide), dissolve neighboring edges to have an angle and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to bevel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to clean the area that you want to fillet/bevel. On the top view  you should have a clean extruded triangle (the area you want to bevel), dissolve or merge the extra/unnecessary vertices in between each one of the apex/vertex angles, and then just normally bevel the single edge (with ctrl. B) That's the way I would do it.